# How to track SFTP's error

Tags: shell-script, sftp

I have 1 script which is used for SFTP. I am getting error for permission issue on target server. I want to track this error in log file. How i can track the sftp's error.
below is my code,

```
    sftp  $TragetUsr@$TargetserIP <<-FIL >> $LOGPATH/$Logfile
        cd $FTPDir
        lcd $FILEPATH
        put $ZipFilename
        bye
    FIL
            SftpStatus=$?
            echo " SftpStatus = $SftpStatus " >> $LOGPATH/$Logfile
```

When i tried to execute this script on prompt it is showing me permission error.
Though I have captured the status of sftp in a variable, It always return me 0.

Error I am getting :Connected to Target server IP.
remote open("Target server path"): Permission denied.

Please help me to capture the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr to the file that stdout points to, then redirect stdout. That allows you to capture the error message

```
sftpError=$(
    sftp  $TragetUsr@$TargetserIP <<-FIL 2>&1 >> $LOGPATH/$Logfile
        cd $FTPDir
        lcd $FILEPATH
        put $ZipFilename
        bye
    FIL
)
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, Thanks for the reply. I have implemented the same thing you have suggested. When I captured the error it is capturing the below string, 
"Connected to target server IP remote open("target server path"): Permission denied" but if SFTP is successful then also this variable capture the "Connected to target server IP". Do i need to check in string whether there is actual error or not ?

Comment: which sftp command is producing the error?

Comment: Yes, you have to check in the string further. Using `2>` redirects all 'stderr' to the file specified. If you wish to track 'stdout' & 'stderr' seperately, you can use two different files.